# Alpine JS: updating properties on a `$ref` object

Tags: javascript, dom, alpine.js

Is it possible to manipulate the styling properties of an HTML object with AlpineJS by accessing it through the `$refs` magic variable?

It seems that I can access the properties of the element, but I can't update them!?!?  After pressing the `button`, nothing happens (from the user point of view).  The shadow just stays in the same place.

I can see from the console-log that the function does run as expected, but as the log shows, the `offsetLeft` property doesn't change.

```html
<style>
.shadow {
    color: rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
    left: 500px;
}
</style>
<div x-data="{
    changeElement() {
        console.log ('shadow at', $refs.shadow.offsetLeft); // prints '500'
        $refs.shadow.offsetLeft = 20;
        console.log ('shadow at', $refs.shadow.offsetLeft); // still prints '500'!?!?!
    }
}">
    <button @click="changeElement()">Change Element</button>
    <div class="shadow" x-ref="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

If `$refs` is the wrong way to approach this, then how do I manipulate the DOM using AlpineJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @LazarNikolic, my problem isn't linked to Alpine.  The `$refs.shadow` object is a JavaScript object, and `offsetLeft` is a read-only property >> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft

The JavaScript inside the `x-data` attribute should read as follows:

```javascript
changeElement() {
    console.log ('shadow at', $refs.shadow.offsetLeft); // prints '500'
    $refs.shadow.style.left = 20 + 'px'; // because in the real-world, 20 is a dynamic element
    console.log ('shadow at', $refs.shadow.offsetLeft); // prints '20'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the issue with alpinejs. The reason why you cannot change offsetLeft is because this is a [read only field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft).

In order to manipulate DOM elements in alpinejs, I suggest you use binding either [style](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#binding-styles) or [class](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind#binding-classes) and you can manipulate the value of the class string by the state of your `data` value.

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }">
  <button x-on:click="open = ! open">Toggle Dropdown</button>
 
  <div :class="open ? '' : 'hidden'">
    Dropdown Contents...
  </div>
</div>
```

The same thing can be done with style object. So, ref magic is used only for querying DOM elements in alpinejs.

Comment: Fundamentally, you're correct and in some circumstances `:style` might work, but it's not really the answer I was looking for (see my answer). As an aside, why does everyone always use that silly `open` / `hidden` example instead of graduating to something a little more complicated and real-life to illustrate that Alpine isn't just there to flash some `<div>`s? Your example doesn't add to your answer at all :-/